# Trying to get qsub to work on my cluster

Tags: centos6, cluster, gridengine

Trying to get qsub to work on my cluster (single node right now but more are coming) So far trying to submit with qsub was returning

```
error: commlib error: got select error (Connection refused)

Unable to run job: unable to send message to qmaster using port 536 on host "nes.local": got send error.

Exiting.
```

I followed some posts on gridengine.org suggesting:

```
/etc/init.d/sgemaster.nes start

/etc/init.d/sgeexecd.nes start
```

this seems to have made progress since now qsub says:

```
Your job 4 ("some_job.qsub") has been submitted
```

but it stays pending forever.

`qhost -f` returns:

```
HOSTNAME                ARCH         NCPU  LOAD  MEMTOT  MEMUSE  SWAPTO  SWAPUS
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
global                  -               -     -       -       -       -       -
nes                     linux-x64      72  0.04  378.4G    6.4G   15.6G     0.0
   hl:arch=linux-x64
   hl:num_proc=72.000000
   hl:mem_total=378.413G
   hl:swap_total=15.625G
   hl:virtual_total=394.038G
   hl:load_avg=0.040000
   hl:load_short=0.080000
   hl:load_medium=0.040000
   hl:load_long=0.010000
   hl:mem_free=371.978G
   hl:swap_free=15.625G
   hl:virtual_free=387.603G
   hl:mem_used=6.435G
   hl:swap_used=0.000
   hl:virtual_used=6.435G
   hl:cpu=0.100000
   hl:m_topology=SCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTSCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTT
   hl:m_topology_inuse=SCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTSCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTTCTT
   hl:m_socket=2.000000
   hl:m_core=36.000000
   hl:np_load_avg=0.000556
   hl:np_load_short=0.001111
   hl:np_load_medium=0.000556
   hl:np_load_long=0.000139
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I get that error if I've forgotten to load the module before running the command.

```
module load torque
```

(Assuming we're talking about torque.)  That should fix it :)
Or put it in `.bashrc` so you don't have to type it each time.